# Typescript - make one type equal to another but with its properties being optional

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have 2 types:

```
type Core = {
  a: boolean;
  b: number;
  c: string
}

type CoreOptions = {
  a?: boolean;
  b?: number;
  c?: string;
}
```

In this example, **CoreOptions** is meant to have some, none, or all of the properties that **Core** has depending on the use case, but never to have a property that isn't in Core.

I am trying to systematically tie them together so that as things evolve and **Core** gets new properties, I only have to change the type **Core**.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Is [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it for the original post. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a type, but make all properties optional, TypeScript has a Utility type called `Partial`. [Official Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype)

Example from the TypeScript Documentation:

```
interface Todo {
  title: string;
  description: string;
}
 
function updateTodo(todo: Todo, fieldsToUpdate: Partial<Todo>) {
  return { ...todo, ...fieldsToUpdate };
}
 
const todo1 = {
  title: "organize desk",
  description: "clear clutter",
};
 
const todo2 = updateTodo(todo1, {
  description: "throw out trash",
});
```